# How to download latest artifact from nexus using jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have a situation where it demands to download latest maven build artifacts from Nexus repository by using Jenkins pipeline? Do anyone have any suggestions?
I have already searched through internet but without any help.
I tried to use "curl" but with no help.

```
  curl -L -u admin:admin123 https://<Nexus URL>/repository/<Repo 
       Name>/version.txt --insecure > 
   version.txt
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are able to get the Maven co-ordinates inside the Jenkis Pipeline then there you can easily download the artifacts from Nexus by using Maven dependency command where you have to pass the variables which you will get from pom.xml file..

For reading pom file inside pipeline, you should have "Pipeline-utility" installed in Jenkins. Then you can store Maven co-ordinates as a variable then pass it inside the script to execute. 
No need to use curl and wget..

Comment: Could you post an example to make this more useful?

Answer (score 2):

You can use maven plugin for this.....`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=http://10.101.15.190:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ -Dartifact=bits:update-service:1.0.3 -Ddest=Setups/Services/update-service.jar`

Comment: You can also use the REST API:  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Search+API#SearchAPI-DownloadingtheLatestVersionofanAsset